# How to search for pages with titles starting with a specific phrase?

Tags: confluence-rest-api

I'm a little confused as to how I'm supposed to put together the CQL search. Basically, I want to grab all pages that have titles starting with a specific set of strings in that specific order. Example:

Searching for "Test Page" should return:

- Test Page
- Test Page (1)
- Test Page Again

It should NOT return:

- Test
- Page
- Page Test
- (1) Test Page
- Again Test Page

I tried many searches, like:

- `title = "Test Page*"`
- `title ~ "Test Page*"`
- `title ~ "Test" AND title ~ "Page*"`

But none of them match exactly what I need. What do I need to change to match the start of a title only?

Alternatively, if it's not possible to search for words at the start of a title, I'd be happy if I can just search something like "Test Page (*)", where * would match any character. Then it should return this:

- Test Page (1)
- Test Page (2)

But not this:

- Test Page
- Test Page Again
- Test
- Page
- Page Test
- (1) Test Page
- Again Test Page

Answer (score 0):

For CQL searches that contain an exact string or phrase, you should [use the CONTAINS operator](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/performing-text-searches-using-cql/#query-terms) and surround the phrase with double quotes as you do in your second example:

```
title ~ "Test Page*"
```

CQL also [supports the single character wildcard search symbol](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/performing-text-searches-using-cql/#wildcard-searches----and--) (?), so for the 'alternate' search you requested, the form should be:

```
title = "Test Page(?)"
```

While [regular expressions syntax is allowed](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Regexp_Searches) between back-slashes, I don't see any evidence that there can be selection by beginning (^) or end ($) of the element. However, using the EQULAS operator with the multi-character wildcard should give the same result:

```
title = "Test Page*"
```

So, according to all available documentation, including documentation for [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Term_Modifiers) upon which CQL is based, you are doing it right. You state that

> 'none of them match exactly what I need.'

Could you provide more information about why these queries were not correct?